# Word/expression for someone who doesn't reciprocate favors?

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-meaning

Is there a word/idiom/expression to refer to someone whom I have helped a lot but doesn't reciprocate any favors even though they are capable of helping me? For example:

> I have helped Peter a lot when he had issues, but he stiffs me when I am going through a tough time. I thought he would help me, as I had helped him a lot in the past. He is ___________.[Someone who doesn't reciprocate favors]

I am looking for a word/idiom/expression other than selfish.

Answer (score 3):

> [Fair-weather friend](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fair-weather_friend) (*noun*) A person who stops being a friend in times of difficulty.

(*Oxford Dictionaries*)

- I have helped Peter a lot when he had issues, but he stiffs me when I am going through a tough time. I thought he would help me, as I had helped him a lot in the past. He is **a fair-weather friend**. [Someone who doesn't reciprocate favors].

Answer (score 2):

He's **[ungrateful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ungrateful)**:

> Not feeling or showing gratitude.

It's not narrow enough; but it's close.

Answer (score 1):

**self-centred**  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-centered)

> preoccupied with oneself and one's affairs, concerned solely with
>   one's own desires, needs, or interests.
>       "he's far too self-centered to care what you do"